TinyMCE editor becomes non editable randomly
I have an Angular 15 project wherein I have used the TinyMCE editor. In the TinyMCE editor ie the textarea randomly becomes noneditable (section highlighted as red in Screenshot 1).
The other editor options like "File, Edit, Insert, View, Format, Table, etc" options are available but they are nonoperational ie I cannot add a table even if the options are available from the editor menu.
Below are the configurations.
this.init = {
        plugins: ['lists', 'link', 'image', 'table', 'help', 'wordcount', 'directionality'],
        promotion: false,
        branding: false,
        elementpath: false,
        menubar: 'file edit insert view format table',
        toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styles | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ltr rtl',
        language: this.translate.getDefaultLang(), // translate service to get language
        height : 300
      };

Screenshot 1


please share the minimal reproducible code if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

I'm iterating a loop where fields and tinyMCE gets rendered dynamically. If the same editor with same configurations is rendered as a singleton it works but while rendering in iteration it becomes non-editable.
